# NSDateFormatter problem

Tags: iphone, nsdate, nsdateformatter

hey i have my date as "7/30/2010". How do i print it as only the Month and Date ie. "7/30"
I tried using NSFormatter but it prints my current date and not which is present in my database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDate *date = dateFromYourDataBase;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"M/dd"];
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter stringFromDate:date]);
[formatter release];
```

Comment: hey it gives me warning: Initialization form incompatible pointer type. Is this because my data in database is stored as text?

Comment: <<That will return 07/30 for the sample input>>
<<How do i print it as only the Month and Date>>
My code print Month and Day
2user391301: Yes, You need to convert your NSString to NSDate first

Comment: Your code which was: `@"MM/dd"` prints two characters for the month and day, even if the month and day values are a single digit. The right format would be `@"M/d", to print single digit values without padding.

Answer (score 0):

You could add some [utility methods](http://macdevelopertips.com/objective-c/objective-c-categories.html) for `NSDate`.

Here is a sample header:

```
@interface NSDate (Utilities)

+ (NSDate *) customDateForString:(NSString *)dateString;
+ (NSDateFormatter *) customDateFormatter;

@end
```

The implementation:

```
@implementation NSDate (Utilities)

static NSDateFormatter *customDateFormatter = nil;

+ (NSDateFormatter *) customDateFormatter {
    // Example: 7/30
    if (!customDateFormatter) {
        customDateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [customDateFormatter setFormatterBehavior:NSDateFormatterBehavior10_4];
        [customDateFormatter setLocale:[[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"] autorelease]];

        // cf. http://unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-6.html#Date_Format_Patterns
        [customDateFormatter setDateFormat:@"M/d"];
    }  
    return customDateFormatter;
}

+ (NSDate *) customDateForString:(NSString *)dateString {
    return [[self customDateFormatter] dateFromString:dateString];
}

@end
```

Whenever you need to parse a date string, you would call it like so:

```
NSLog(@"Parsed date: %@", [NSDate customDateForString:@"7/30/2010"]); // Parsed date: 7/30
```